# iOS: Is there a way to know whether a contact comes from Facebook and his FBID?

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts, addressbook

Can someone tell me if it's possible to get the Facebook ID from a contact's in the  AddressBook?

I've been using the **[RHAddressBook](https://github.com/heardrwt/RHAddressBook)** library but can't seem to know how to go around this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If the app owner is logged on to facebook via the device, then you can (with their permission) fetch their facebook friends, and then once you have a list of their friends you will have the fbids and could compare the name's of the friends in the contacts list to see if there is a match (though even if the names match exactly it doesn't mean its the same person).

I don't think there is a way to get the fbid from a name, but check out the facebook ios documentation to confirm.